# How to reclassify CORINE Land Cover with QGIS 3.10?

Tags: qgis, reclassify

I am working with QGIS. The CORINE Land Cover is a GeoPackage. I would like to reclassify CORINE Land Cover into 3 categories. The codes for the three categories are 211, 212 and 313. In order to use `r.reclass` I need to create a reclassification table first.

How to make the reclassification table?

Comment: The [help section](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/r.reclass.html) include examples how to.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in QGIS, you can also use SAGA's "Reclassify Values ​​(Simple)" algorithm. You can easily create the lookup table / reclassification table there and then reclassify your CLC data.

If you have to use Grass, you can create a .txt file and simply replace the "old" values ​​with the new ones, or write your rules in the "Reclass rules text" field (see below).

```
0 = NULL
1 2     = 1 developed
3       = 2 agriculture
4 6     = 3 herbaceous
7 8 9   = 4 shrubland
10 thru 18 = 5 forest
20      = 6 water
21      = 7 sediment
```

If you are working with a script, you can also write the reclassify rules in the .txt file.

```
# use this command or save rules with editor in textfile "landuserecl.txt"
echo "0 = NULL
1 2     = 1 developed
3       = 2 agriculture
4 6     = 3 herbaceous
7 8 9   = 4 shrubland
10 thru 18 = 5 forest
20      = 6 water
21      = 7 sediment" > landuserecl.txt
```

Comment: Quick question from me. I would like to reclassify the lcc into 3 categories: 1) agricultural areas, 2)  Forest and semi natural areas and 3) wetlands and water bodies.
Would it be the Reclass rules text field like the following one:
0 = null
1 = 1 agriculture
2 = 2 Forest and semi natural areas 
3 = 3 wetlands and water bodies

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like to use grass module r.reclass

Comment: No, I don't know the meaning behind the CLC-ID, but it has to be written as follows.       
211 = 1 agricultural areas
212 = 2 forest and semi natural areas
313 = 3 wetlands and water bodies                                                                         
And before you can reclassify your data, you have to rasterize the shapefile.

Comment: Lovely! Now it makes sense. I got it!